# ORA-01722 at Insert via DB link

Tags: sql, oracle, insert, dblink

I'm using oracle SQL and want to insert my data into a remote DB via a link.

```
 insert into V_ADITO_ONLINE_BEITRITT@MDB.IGM (<82 different columnNames>)
 values (<82 different values>);
```

As far as I checked all datatypes, columns and values match up, yet I get this error:

```
Errorcode 1722, SQL-Status 42000: ORA-01722: Invalid Number
ORA-02063: previous line of MDB.IGM
```

I'd appreciate it a lot if someone could help me with this error.
 
V_ADITO_ONLINE_BEITRITT is a view if that helps in any way.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Source Orafaq.com](http://www.orafaq.com/wiki/ORA-01722)

An ORA-01722 ("invalid number") error occurs when an attempt is made to convert a character string into a number

**When doing an INSERT INTO ... VALUES (...)**
One of the data items you are trying to insert is an invalid number.

Locate and correct it.
If all of the numbers appear to be valid, then you probably have your columns out of order, and an item in the VALUES clause is being inserted into a NUMBER column instead of the expected VARCHAR2 column. This can happen when a table has columns added or removed.

If you are doing an INSERT or UPDATE, with a sub query supplying the values. Obviously, the preceding considerations apply here as well. What makes this more complicated is that the offending character string is hidden as a row in a table. The fix is to identify the row (or rows) which has the non-numeric string, and either change the data (if it is in error) or add something to the sub query to avoid selecting it. The problem is in identifying the exact row.
Assuming that the errant datum is an alphabetic character, one can use the following query:

```
SELECT ...  WHERE UPPER(col) != LOWER(col)
```

where col is the column with the bad data.

Answer (score 0):

Try to comment a half of fieldnames and values and check if ORA-1722 still exists. When you found error-containing half, try to comment half of it and so on. Locate exact field & value which produces a problem, check and repair them.